# We define a map $T: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ s.t $T(f)=\int_0^1 fgdx$. Determine $||T||$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $g \in L^ {\infty}$

> we define a map $T: L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ s.t $T(f)=\int_0^1 fgdx$. Determine $||T||$.

**I have seen that** $||T||=\sup \{||T(f)|| : ||f||=1\} \leq ||g||_{\infty}$

How to prove the converse? I also know that the set $E_n=\{x \in [0,1]:  |g(x) >||g||_{\infty} - \frac1n\}$ has positive measure.

So please check what I have done is right or not and provide the answer in details.

Comment: Try to use your set $E_n$ to make a function $f$ to apply $T$ to.

Comment: I have tried to use simple function and mct but in vain. If possible if you could write in detail in answer.

Comment: You are supposed to solve it, not me.  How about first doing the simpler case where $g \ge 0$?

Comment: We can approximate by characteristic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: My solution]

I hope it helps. (................)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Note that $g$ also lies in $L_{2}([0,1])$. By the Cauchy-Schwarz we have ...